# Bootstrap nested layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

You can see from the jfiddle link below what I'm trying to do and what the problem is. On a large screen I get a big space at the bottom which I can't remove. On the mobile I'd like each of the four images to take up the full screen but can't get it to work. Been trying to sort this for a day and I'm just going in circles now.  Any help would be appreciated.

cheers
mike.
http://jsfiddle.net/batman13/wpnLjsuo/`

```
            <div class="col-sm-6 fill50 hidden-xs" style=
             "background-image:url('http://ajsroofingsolutions.com/images/sony_xperia-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg');">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Jonny 5 Alive Big Screen </h2>
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="col-xs-12 fill100 visible-xs" style=
             "background-image:url('http://ajsroofingsolutions.com/images/sony_xperia-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg');">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Jonny 5 Alive mobile</h2>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 fill50 hidden-xs" style=
             "background-image:url('http://ajsroofingsolutions.com/images/branding.jpg');">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Jonny 5 Alive2 Big Screen</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 fill100 visible-xs" style=
             "background-image:url('http://ajsroofingsolutions.com/images/branding.jpg');">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Jonny 5 Alive mobile</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" style="height:50%">
            <div class="col-sm-12 fill100 hidden-xs" style=
             "background-image:url('http://ajsroofingsolutions.com/images/apple_wooden-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg');">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Jonny 5 Alive3 Big Screen</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="height:50%">
            <div class="col-xs-12 fill100 visible-xs" style=
             "background-image:url('http://ajsroofingsolutions.com/images/apple_wooden-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg');">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Jonny 5 Alive3 Mobile</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 fill50 hidden-xs" style=
    "background-image:url('http://ajsroofingsolutions.com/images/background.jpg');">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h2>Jonny 5 Alive Big Screen</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 fill100 visible-xs" style=
     "background-image:url('http://ajsroofingsolutions.com/images/background.jpg');">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h2>Jonny 5 Alive Mobile</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

White space issue is because of this:

```
    <div class="row" style="height:50%">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 fill100 visible-xs" style=
         "background-image:url('http://ajsroofingsolutions.com/images/apple_wooden-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg');">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Jonny 5 Alive3 Mobile3</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

You are setting the height of the row and hiding the content, so the row is still showing.  You need to hide the row so move your `.visible-xs` and `.hidden-xs` to the rows.  After that wanting the full viewport height on the mobile is going to require you to set up a media query and move your inline height styling out into a CSS file.  For example:

```
    <div class="row visible-xs" id="test">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 fill100" style=
         "background-image:url('http://ajsroofingsolutions.com/images/apple_wooden-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg');">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Jonny 5 Alive3 Mobile3</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#test{
    height: 50%;
}

@media(max-width: 500px){
    #test{    
       height: 100vh;
    }
}
```